# Invesitgate the convergence/divergence of the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series: $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\ln n)^{10}\sin\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

I tried all known tests but to no avail. The ratio test fails and so does the root test. Comparison test with $\dfrac1{n^2}$ fails. Integral test is unhelpful because the function cannot easily be integrated.

Comment: is the sine a part of the exponent? Please format appropriately.

Comment: Its ln^10(n)*sin(1/n^2)

Comment: uhh... what? Do you want the convergence of that sequence, or the convergence of its partial sums? Your last edit indicates the latter (easy), but the original pointed to the latter.

Comment: I was trying to change it to something that is easy to understand; its meant to be an infinite series. How do you guys convert it to MathJax???

Comment: I don't think there's a mathjax editor - just learn the symbol names. The code for $\Sigma_{a=0}^b$ is `\Sigma_{a=0}^b`

Comment: use \infty in place of \infinity

Comment: @rst thanks. You were faster than my googlefu

Answer (score 2):

Notice for all $x \ge 1$, $\log x < x$. This implies for all integer $n \ge 1$,

$$\frac{\log n}{20} = \log n^{1/20} < n^{1/20} \implies (\log n)^{10} < 20^{10} \sqrt{n}$$

Since $\displaystyle\;\;\sin \frac{1}{n^2} \le \frac{1}{n^2}\;\;$ for $n \ge 1$, we have
$$(\log n)^{10} \sin \frac{1}{n^2} \le \frac{20^{10}}{n^{\frac32}}$$
and hence $\displaystyle\;\;\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\log n)^{10} \sin\frac{1}{n^2}\;\;$converges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$n^{3/2}(\ln n)^{10}\sin\frac1{n^2} \sim (\ln n)^{10}\frac1{n^{1/2}} \to 0, \quad n\to \infty.$$

Comment: This proves nothing

Comment: Sorry, misread series as "sequence". Now corrected.

Comment: I am assuming that you compared it with 1/n^2/3) which is divergent, if that is so and the limit is zero it doesn't say anything about the original series.

Comment: $n^{-3/2}$, not $n^{-2/3}$.

Comment: Oops, you're right

Comment: proving that the limit of $$(\ln n)^{10}\frac1{n^{1/2}}$$ is zero is quite long

Comment: For any $\alpha>0$ we have $\frac{\ln x}{x^\alpha} \to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$. This is very well known and different proofs of this fact can also be found in many posts of this forum.

Comment: In this case, the numerator is ln(x)^c, although its the same thing

Comment: $(\ln n)^{10}\frac1{n^{1/2}} = (\frac{\ln n}{n^{1/20}})^{10}$.

Comment: Just wondering how would you solve it if it was ln(n)^n  and changings the sin(1/n^2) to sin(1/n^n)

Comment: $(\ln n)^{n}\frac1{n^{1/2}}$? Then $(\frac{\ln n}{n^{1/2n}})^{n} \to \infty$ (because $\sqrt[n]{n} \to 1$) and the series diverges.

Comment: sin(1/n^2) to sin(1/n^n)

Comment: any thoughts on how to do it?

Comment: Then $\sim \left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)^n$ and $\frac{\ln n}{n}\to 0$, so converges.

Comment: What is your comparison series in this case?

Comment: No comparison is needed in this case. Use Cauchy's test.

Comment: Never heard of it before... time to research it

Comment: Is it the Cauchy condensation test??

Comment: No, Cauchy's root test: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test

Comment: I know the root test...I get it now. So your using DCT and root test together all under the assumption that sin(x)<x for all positive values rite? Thanks :)